# Zoo Time-series - extend x-axis in plot

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I created a time-series with zoo (following suggestions in another question that ts() is not good for daily time-series). I would like to extend the x-axis beyond the dates from my zoo object (in order to overlay a second time-series - neither "add=T" nor points() seem to work for zoo plots). I need to overlay (par(new=T)) the second time-series because the two have different scales. 
However, if I try to adjust xlim, it plots the axes, but not the actual data.

```
2017.ts<-read.zoo(2017.day, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

2017.ts
            norm_mean
2017-01-27    7.500000
2017-01-31    13.666667
2017-02-08    12.833333
2017-02-15    14.000000
2017-02-17    18.200000
2017-02-23    10.833333
2017-03-03    11.000000
2017-03-06    13.333333
2017-03-07    14.833333
2017-03-08    18.000000
2017-03-09    10.600000
2017-03-10    5.666667
2017-03-16    17.000000
2017-03-20    10.500000
2017-03-29    5.000000
2017-03-30    2.000000
2017-03-31    2.166667
2017-04-04    2.666667
2017-04-11    3.750000

plot(2017.ts, type="h", lwd=5, lend=1, col="grey", xlab="Date")
plot(2017.ts, type="h", lwd=5, lend=1, col="grey", xlab="Date",xlim=as.Date(c("01-01-2017", "01-05-2017")) )
```

[image: Time-series]

[image: Adjusted x-axis]

Edit to include data for the second ts.

```
z2

        v2 
2017-01-04 108.65521 
2017-01-05 109.13615 
2017-01-06 108.78080 
2017-01-07 108.27312 
2017-01-08 109.09156 
2017-01-09 108.13882 
2017-01-10 108.79868 
2017-01-11 109.08090 
2017-01-12 110.09045 
2017-01-13 108.89611 
2017-01-14 111.21378 
2017-01-15 111.70625 
2017-01-16 113.30840 
2017-01-17 112.95767 
2017-01-18 110.57698 
2017-01-19 111.67750 
2017-01-20 112.11809 
2017-01-21 112.36285 
2017-01-22 111.72885 
2017-01-23 111.56948 
2017-01-24 113.18226 
2017-01-25 114.50997 
2017-01-26 112.59635 
2017-01-27 112.89517
2017-01-28 113.85590 
2017-01-29 113.66267 
2017-01-30 113.27187
2017-01-31 114.49236 
2017-02-01 113.46934 
2017-02-02 116.58854 
2017-02-03 114.50764 
2017-02-04 115.47986 
2017-02-05 115.34931 
2017-02-06 115.43250 
2017-02-07 114.70101 
2017-02-08 113.19042 
2017-02-09 115.53726 
2017-02-10 115.05983 
2017-02-11 115.34476 
2017-02-12 115.49007 
2017-02-13 114.96326 
2017-02-14 115.37941 
2017-02-15 115.40066 
2017-02-16 116.49903
2017-02-17 115.05514 
2017-02-18 115.72139 
2017-02-19 116.44944 
2017-02-20 116.38858 
2017-02-21 116.52819 
2017-02-22 116.13941 
2017-02-23 114.54677 
2017-02-24 115.84712 
2017-02-25 116.91059 
2017-02-26 115.72712 
2017-02-27 116.68500 
2017-02-28 117.56170 
2017-03-01 117.17802 
2017-03-02 115.96913 
2017-03-03 116.71031 
2017-03-04 116.30385 
2017-03-05 115.48656 
2017-03-06 115.64056 
2017-03-07 116.25858 
2017-03-08 115.88340 
2017-03-09 114.34972 
2017-03-10 114.59559 
2017-03-11 115.07535 
2017-03-12 115.34625 
2017-03-13 114.80948 
2017-03-14 115.02052  
2017-03-15 114.85764
```

[image: Time-series with adjusted x-axis]

```
xlim<-range(c(time(2017.ts), time(z2)))
plot(2017.ts, type = "h", lwd = 1, col = "blue", xlim = xlim)
```

However,

```
points(z2,col="red")
```

does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally one does this by merging the two series together and plotting them all at once. Using the data in the Note at the end we have the following code.  (`screens = 1` will  use a single panel rather than plotting each in a separate panel.)

```
z <- merge(z1, z2)
plot(z, type = "h", col = c("blue", adjustcolor("red", .4)), screens = 1)
```

giving (continued after figure):

[image: screenshot]

Although not recommended due to the unnecessary extra code, if you really want to do it in two steps then:

```
xlim <- range(c(time(z1), time(z2)))
ylim <- range(c(coredata(z1), coredata(z2)))
plot(z1, type = "h", col = "blue", xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim)
points(z2, type = "h", col = adjustcolor("red", .4))
```

giving (continued after figure):

[image: screenshot]

### Note

```
Lines <- "
2017-01-27    7.500000
2017-01-31    13.666667
2017-02-08    12.833333
2017-02-15    14.000000
2017-02-17    18.200000
2017-02-23    10.833333
2017-03-03    11.000000
2017-03-06    13.333333
2017-03-07    14.833333
2017-03-08    18.000000
2017-03-09    10.600000
2017-03-10    5.666667
2017-03-16    17.000000
2017-03-20    10.500000
2017-03-29    5.000000
2017-03-30    2.000000
2017-03-31    2.166667
2017-04-04    2.666667
2017-04-11    3.750000"

Lines2 <- "
2017-01-04 108.65521 
2017-01-05 109.13615 
2017-01-06 108.78080 
2017-01-07 108.27312 
2017-01-08 109.09156 
2017-01-09 108.13882 
2017-01-10 108.79868 
2017-01-11 109.08090 
2017-01-12 110.09045 
2017-01-13 108.89611 
2017-01-14 111.21378 
2017-01-15 111.70625 
2017-01-16 113.30840 
2017-01-17 112.95767 
2017-01-18 110.57698 
2017-01-19 111.67750 
2017-01-20 112.11809 
2017-01-21 112.36285 
2017-01-22 111.72885 
2017-01-23 111.56948 
2017-01-24 113.18226 
2017-01-25 114.50997 
2017-01-26 112.59635 
2017-01-27 112.89517
2017-01-28 113.85590 
2017-01-29 113.66267 
2017-01-30 113.27187
2017-01-31 114.49236 
2017-02-01 113.46934 
2017-02-02 116.58854 
2017-02-03 114.50764 
2017-02-04 115.47986 
2017-02-05 115.34931 
2017-02-06 115.43250 
2017-02-07 114.70101 
2017-02-08 113.19042 
2017-02-09 115.53726 
2017-02-10 115.05983 
2017-02-11 115.34476 
2017-02-12 115.49007 
2017-02-13 114.96326 
2017-02-14 115.37941 
2017-02-15 115.40066 
2017-02-16 116.49903
2017-02-17 115.05514 
2017-02-18 115.72139 
2017-02-19 116.44944 
2017-02-20 116.38858 
2017-02-21 116.52819 
2017-02-22 116.13941 
2017-02-23 114.54677 
2017-02-24 115.84712 
2017-02-25 116.91059 
2017-02-26 115.72712 
2017-02-27 116.68500 
2017-02-28 117.56170 
2017-03-01 117.17802 
2017-03-02 115.96913 
2017-03-03 116.71031 
2017-03-04 116.30385 
2017-03-05 115.48656 
2017-03-06 115.64056 
2017-03-07 116.25858 
2017-03-08 115.88340 
2017-03-09 114.34972 
2017-03-10 114.59559 
2017-03-11 115.07535 
2017-03-12 115.34625 
2017-03-13 114.80948 
2017-03-14 115.02052  
2017-03-15 114.85764"

library(zoo)
z1 <- read.zoo(text = Lines)
z2 <- read.zoo(text = Lines2)
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot. You are right, normally one would just merge the two time-series and plot them with screens=1, but my two time-series are a magnitude different. I just want to overlay them for visualization (they're essentially the same data just from two different methods). I tried to add my second time-series with points(), but it's not plotting anything. I'll edit my original post to include the data of the second ts.

Comment: The first alternative works with your data and if we set `ylim` as well then the second one does too.  Make sure you have the latest version of R and zoo and in a **fresh R session** copy and paste the code from the Note at the end and then copy and paste the first alternative and then copy and paste the second alternative.  I have shown the output that is given.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about adjusting the ylim. I wanted to put the second ts on the secondary x-axis. I guess that only works with par(new=T)

Comment: If you want a custom axis specify `xaxt = "n"` in the `plot` command and then use the `axis` function to supply your own axis.  See `?axis` and possibly `?Axis` and `?axTicks` .